# How do I save the stage upon every KineticJS event?

Tags: javascript, json, html, kineticjs

I understand that a KineticJS stage can be saved to JSON with the stage.toJSON function. I would like to perform this action any time the stage changes in any way. For example, I would want to run the toJSON function if a shape was moved via draggable, a shape's size is changed, the inner contents are changed dynamically, a shape is added dynamically, etc. etc. etc. I would really prefer not to specifically listen for all of the possible events and run the same code for each. I would just prefer to capture all events in one call. Is there anything that could help me do this? I realize there could be a performance hit. Saving the stage upon any change being made to it is a business requirement. Fortunately, this functionality is limited to only a few users. Thank you.

Comment: So try it...there's no universal `onChange` handler so you must stick a function call in all the applicable `.on` event handlers and in that function do `stage.toJSON` (likely result: crash!).

Comment: I think you missed the point and I am sure there is no likely crash..

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify your question for me? :-)

Comment: Please create a JSFIDDLE of your code, so that we can help you precisely

Comment: What exactly would I post as a fiddle? No offense, the question should be pretty clear, I think. But, if you ask me a particular question, I can further clarify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I save the stage upon every KineticJS event?

**Answer:** Call `stage.toJSON` when any KineticJS event occurs.

> Is there any KineticJS event handler that listens for any-and-all events?

**Answer:** Actually, there is one Draconian option.

You could ask to listen for every event that KineticJS can generate because the .on() method can accept multiple space-delimited event types.

You would be left with the task of deciding whether to `stage.toJSON` based on the eventType plus your design considerations.

Nodes can listen for these event types:

```
// a space-delimited list of all node events that KineticJS can listen for
var allNodeEvents="mouseover mousemove mouseout mouseenter mouseleave mousedown mouseup click dblclick touchstart touchmove touchend tap dbltap dragstart dragmove dragend";
```

The stage can listen for these event types:

```
// a space-delimited list of all stage events that KineticJS can listen for
var allStageEvents="contentMouseover contentMousemove contentMouseout contentMousedown contentMouseup contentClick contentDblclick contentTouchstart contentTouchmove contentTouchend contentTap contentDblTap";
```

You can listen for any-and-all Node+Stage events like this:

```
// listen for all possible Node events
node.on(allNodeEvents,function(event){

    // get the type of this event
    var eventType=event.type;

    // Do stage.toJSON 
    //(or not based on eventType and other design specific considerations

});


// listen for all possible Stage events
stage.on(allStageEvents,function(event){

    // get the type of this event
    var eventType=event.type;

    // Do stage.toJSON 
    //(or not based on eventType and other design specific considerations

});
```

Comment: Yep, thanks! That did it. I didn't think about just specifying all of them in a list, let alone using node and stage as the selectors.